# Send each line of a multiline string to a list within a for loop

Tags: python, string, list

I have a multi-line string which looks like this:

```
something1
something2
something3
```

I'm wanting to send each line of this string to a list so that `result[0] = something1` and so on.

I have tried doing this:

```
for line in tableOut:
        results.append(line.strip().split('\n'))
```

However, this makes every character of the string sent to a unique index in the list.

For example:

```
[['s'], ['o'], ['m'], ['e'], ['t'], ['h'], ['i'], ['n'], ['g'], ['1']]
```

Why isn't this working, and how can I send each line of a multi line string to a unique index in a list within a for loop?

Comment: Look at the string function `split()` To get a list of lines then the `for x in y` operation on list y will assign each entry in y to x - but be careful to make sure that the resulting lines are clean of \r or \n etc. So perhaps use `strip()` on the results of split

Comment: `[x_ for x_ in [x.strip() for x in data.splitlines()] if x_]`. The fixed version of your code could be `for line in tableOut.split('\n'): results.append(line.strip())`.

Comment: `tableOut.split()`.  (Iterating through a string yields the characters.)

Comment: `results = tableOut.splitlines()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tableOut` is a string: a sequence of characters.  Naming your loop index `line` is misleading, as the iterator over a string returns individual characters.  That's your major problem.

Instead, `split` your string into a list of lines -- as @sardok has already summarized.  Strip the individual lines.  You can do this with a list comprehension isntead of an explicit loop.

```
results = [strip(line) for line in tableOut.split('\n')]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you meant by "multi-line" string but lets say it's something like this:

```
tableOut = 'something1\n' \
           'something2\n' \
           'something3'
```

Then you could do:

```
result = []
for line in tableOut.split('\n'):
    result.append(line.strip())
```

Not the most pythonic way, but it's similar to what you were trying to do.

Comment: I provided an example of a multi-line string in the question.

Comment: Yes, ok, i could've interpreted that.